# How to reference static files from lua package?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I have some static file in my luarock which I include using `copy_directories`. Now I would like to know how I can references these files from the lua code? Or alternatively what the best method is to reference static files included with a luarock.

Comment: Use `package.path`, and later, you can `require`, or use relative paths using the `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: https://github.com/hishamhm/datafile

Comment: Thanks, @siffiejoe that seems to make life easier